# laravel mix стартует на ipv6

Tags: node.js, laravel-mix

При запуске npm run watch по заданному порту не зайти висит. Проблему похоже нашел netstat говорит что они висять на адресе ipv6. Хотя он вообще вычищен в системе.

```
tcp6       0      0 :::3000                 :::*                    LISTEN      12221/node      
tcp6       0      0 :::3001                 :::*                    LISTEN      12221/node
```

Куда копать?

Comment: копай в /etc/hosts

Comment: спсб в hosts @norbornen 127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.0.1 domain.com
xxx.x.xx.xxx  Debian-81-jessie-64-LAMP
xxx.x.xx.xxx root-server3